# No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:completion:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this code to switch view controllers programmatically. When I build and run, I get this error: No visible `@interface` for `ViewController` declares the selector `presentModalViewController:animated:completion:`

Code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:pSearchViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I get rid of completion:nil then I get the warning `presentModalViewController:animated` is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0. What do I do?

Comment: [self.navigationController presentViewController:pSearchViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `presentmodalviewcontroller:` is deprecated. Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead. Your code:

```
[self presentViewController:pSearchViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)alertview:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

     if (buttonIndex==1){
         UIViewController *newview = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
         [self presentedViewController:newview animated:YES completion:nil];
     }

}
```